# How do I trim a hash?

Tags: ruby

Given this hash:

```
h = { "01"=>0, "02"=>0, "03"=>5, "04"=>6, "05"=>0, "06"=>0, "07"=>0, "08"=>7, "09"=>8, "10"=>0, "11"=>0, "12"=>0 }
```

how do I trim it to get this result:

```
h = { "03"=>5, "04"=>6, "05"=>0, "06"=>0, "07"=>0, "08"=>7, "09"=>8 }
```

that is, I want to remove the zero values from the beginning and the end of the hash.

Comment: As far as I know, the keys of the hashes in Ruby are not ordered, so you need to specify which order of keys (and/or values) you want. You can use a sort routine for that.

Comment: Since Ruby 1.9, hashes are ordered ... meaning they remember the order in which keys have been added. Still, if you want to store data and need to do sorting etc ... an Array is more appropriate

Comment: If you need to store data and access it quickly, an array is not appropriate. Sorting a hash isn't difficult but it is more so than an array, however, how the data contained is being used/accessed is what I use to decide between an array or a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `break` to stop the execution.

```
h.delete_if{|k,v| v == 0 ? true : break }
h.reverse_each{|k,v| v == 0 ? h.delete(k) : break }
```

Comment: Doesn't remove any from the end.

Comment: `h.reverse_each{|k,v| v == 0 ? h.delete(k) : break }`

Answer (score 1):

Improved CubaLibre's answer:

```
Hash[h.drop_while { |k,v| v == 0 }.reverse.drop_while { |k,v| v == 0 }.reverse]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[h.drop_while {|k,v| v == 0 }.take_while {|k,v| v != 0}]
```

This version makes assumptions about the ordering of keys in the Hash which is not a good idea.

Perhaps a combination of select and reject will read better.

Comment: I'd +1 it for being functional, but the tail-trimming isn't right.

Comment: I was in the middle of editing it when my computer ran out of juice! Never mind. Thanks for the +1

Comment: But I wasn't referring to "0"/0, the problem is if you have zeros in the middle of the hash, i.e. Try with `{a: 0, b: 1, c: 0, d: 2, e: 0}`.

Comment: True that. I guess that makes `reverse` a necessity.